# Set Django field to function result

Tags: django, field

I want to create a IntegerField and set the value according to a .json that I download so my code is:

```
class InstagramShowcase(models.Model):

def numero(name):
    datos = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=' + str(name) +'&client_id=573c505763dd4bee80d29d105f901ab5')
    resultados = json.load(datos)

    return resultados["data"][0]["id"]

name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
instagramUser = models.CharField(max_length=40)
website = models.URLField(blank=True)
numberid = models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.numberid = self.numero(self.name)
```

but when I try to syncdb this appears:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'numero'
```

What is the right way to assing a Field the value of a function?

Comment: Move the function outside the class.

Comment: @karthikr i tried it but when I syncdb It says that 0 arguments where given

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to define an attribute of a model class as being dependent upon a model instance; that's not possible, as the instance does not (and cannot) exist before your define the class and its attributes.

To get the effect you want, override the save() method of the model class. Make any changes you want to the instance necessary, then call the superclass's method to do the actual saving. Here's a quick example.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.numberid:
        self.numberid = self.numero()
    super(InstagramShowcase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

also define the 'numero' function inside the class to make this work.
Read in detail about Overriding model methods [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).

Comment: It returns AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: I read about it and changed my answered accordingly see if that helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've asked to a friend and finaly I have the solution:

As @kviktor I added super(InstagramShowcase, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs) and after it

```
if self.name:
        if not self.numberid:
            self.numberid = numero(self.name)
            self.save()
```

In this way the when I enter a new object in the admin if there is no name, it doesn't make a query and I have 1 error less. When I save once is edited there is a name and, like @kviktor said, to avoid make multiples queries when i create one, I check if there is already a number id and if there is It does nothing.

Sorry for my english I hope you understand me. Thanks for the help